# JavaFx customize button's look

Tags: java, image, button, javafx

I uploaded an image to my button, but it looks like this:
[image]

The button isn't shaped like the image, and the button colors are still visible on the edges. Is there a way to change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
button.setPadding(Insets.EMPTY);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
button.setStyle("-fx-background-radius: 0; -fx-padding: 0; -fx-background-color: transparent;");
```

you can also apply the style in a css